# why MATLAB gpuarray is much slower in just adding two matrices?

Tags: matlab, gpgpu, gpu

I have recently employed MATLAB CUDA library for some absolutely simple matrix calculations on gpu. But the performance results are very strange.
could any body help me understand what exactly is going on and how I can solve the issue. Thanks in advance.
Please note that the following codes are run on geforce GTX TITAN black gpu.

assume a0,a1,...a6 be 1000*1000 gpuarrays and U=0.5 and V=0.0

```
titan = gpuDevice();
tic();

for i=1:10000
a6(1,1)=(0.5.*(a5(1,1)-a0(1,1)))-(a1(1,1)+a2(1,1)+a3(1,1))-(a5(1,1).*U./3.0)-(a5(1,1).*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5(1,1).*a4(1,1));  
end

wait(titan);
time = toc()
```

the result for time=17.98 seconds

now re-defining a0,a1,...a6 and U and V for employment on cpu and calculating the time needed:

```
tic();

for i=1:10000
a6(1,1)=(0.5.*(a5(1,1)-a0(1,1)))-(a1(1,1)+a2(1,1)+a3(1,1))-(a5(1,1).*U./3.0)-(a5(1,1).*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5(1,1).*a4(1,1));  
end

time= toc()
```

the result for time=0.0098 seconds

therefore more than 1800 times faster on cpu!!!!

then I decided to do the previous calculations on the whole matrix rather than specific elements, and here are the results:

Results for the run on gpu:

```
titan = gpuDevice();
tic();
for i=1:10000
a6=(0.5.*(a5-a0))-(a1+a2+a3)-(a5.*U./3.0)-(a5.*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5.*a4);  
end
wait(titan);
time = toc()
```

the result for time=6.32 seconds
which means that the operation on the whole matrix is much faster than on a specific element!

Results for the run on CPU:

```
tic();
for i=1:10000
a6=(0.5.*(a5-a0))-(a1+a2+a3)-(a5.*U./3.0)-(a5.*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5.*a4);  
end

time= toc()
```

the result for time=35.2 seconds

AND HERE IS THE MOST SURPRISING RESULT:
assuming a0,a1,...a6 and U and V to be just 1*1 gpuarrays and running the following:

```
titan = gpuDevice();
tic();
for i=1:10000
a6=(0.5.*(a5-a0))-(a1+a2+a3)-(a5.*U./3.0)-(a5.*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5.*a4);  
end
wait(titan);
time = toc()
```

the result for time=7.8 seconds

it is even slower than the corresponding 1000*1000 case!

Unfortunately the line
a6(1,1)=(0.5.*(a5(1,1)-a0(1,1)))-(a1(1,1)+a2(1,1)+a3(1,1))-(a5(1,1).*U./3.0)-(a5(1,1).*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5(1,1).*a4(1,1));
is one of the lines among about 100 lines, all in a single for-loop and this line proved itself as a real bottleneck taking about 50% of all calculation time needed! 
could anybody help me? note that transferring this part of calculations on cpu is not a choice because the bottleneck line is in a for-loop and sending a1,...a6 to cpu and calling the results to gpu in each iteration is much more time consuming.
any advice is really really appreciated.

Comment: I've just verified this with my Titan black, with matlab 2011b - timings are of course different but tendencies are the same. A few thoughts: Referring to the 5 code blocks its not surprising, that 2 is much faster than 1 because CPU is much faster than a single GPU multiproc and CPU will cache all values. 3 and 4 agree - GPU is faster. 1 vs 3: maybe indexing is costly on gpu somehow? I found some sources on the www stating that indexing is not supported on GPU, but no details as to versions of Matlab. No idea for 5. General remarks: use * and / instead .* and ./ for scalar, its faster.

Comment: Some more: are you using single precision gpuArrays? (doesnt change a lot, but my matlab version is rather old). Also, for me, defining U and V on cpu or gpu makes a small yet non negligible difference. Furthermore it might not be fair measuring a 10.000x for loop since maybe each iteration a new cuda kernel might be created or sth.  CPU is at 100% for the GPU tests here. Then there is the question how you found that this single statement takes 50%? Is that reliable? E.g. comparing that single line computation time to the whole time of your loop is unfair. You could maybe write your own Kernel

Comment: Thomas, I use double precision, however i think single precision could result in a real boost. on the other hand, by 50%, I meant that there are about 100 lines of code in the for-loop but profiling shows that about 50% of the execution time is for this special line.

Comment: Is there a gpu-profiler in matlab for this? Or what do you use? I mean, you cannot profile reliably by removing this or that part from your code and then benchmarking it since a new and differently optimized kernel will be created. If you tried profiling this way, the conclusion that this line really is the bottleneck might be wrong.

Comment: Thomas, I used the original MATLAB profiler, but to increase accuracy, I added a "wait" command after certain lines

Answer (score 1):

ehsan,

Titan is powerful.

I hope the following might help.

1> GPU has many (from hundred to thousands) low frequency **stream** cores, which means they have to execute the same instructions. So, they are very good at [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD) instructions. 
If you are doing to compute only one element of a matrix (the first example and the last), GPU is definitely not good at this.

2> For the second test, please involve the index i into the expression to eliminate optimization from compiler. Or, you can try to change 10000 to 50000 to see whether there is a difference.

```
for i=1:10000
a6=i*(0.5.*(a5-a0))-(a1+a2+a3)-(a5.*U./3.0)-(a5.*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5.*a4);  
end
```

3> CPU has its own [Vector Processing Unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_processor#SIMD) (VPU), which is also aimed for SIMD. The only problem is that, it is quite small, from 64 bit to 256 bit. So, if the matrix is small, CPU is much better than GPU. Therefore, to see the performance benefit of GPU, you can try a larger dimension, say, 5000x5000.

Please let me know if you have any further results on this.

Comment: Ray, I do not intend to just check or compare the cpu performance vs the gpu, therefore multiplication of i to the right hand side of the commands and checking the performance might not be the case. on the other hand, even accounting the SIMD definition you pointed, how could it be explained that the execution time of the third test for a matrix of size 1*1 is comparably higher than the results for the second test?

Answer (score 1):

I think your second GPU result (i.e. vectorised GPU calls) is the most pertinent - GPUs are most efficient when operating on large amounts of data in a vectorised fashion. In your case, you can probably get even better performance by converting your expression into an `arrayfun` call. `arrayfun` allows MATLAB to convert the entire expression into a single operation on the GPU, which takes best advantage of the (huge) available memory bandwidth of the device.

As to your problem calculating `a6(1,1)` - perhaps it might be best to calculate the whole array (i.e. don't index the right-hand-side expressions) and then index afterwards. Something like

```
tmp = (0.5.*(a5-a0))-(a1+a2+a3)-(a5.*U./3.0)-(a5.*V./2.0)+(0.25.*a5.*a4);
a6(1,1) = tmp(1,1);
```

Comment: Edric, I'll test both suggestions "arrayfun" and the "not indexing" idea and let you know the results. still any opinion why the third test (1*1 matrix) is slower than the second(1000*1000 matrix)?

Comment: I must admit I'm not entirely sure why the scalar case turns out actually slower - it might be to do with the precise form of the kernels that get launched and how well they're able to be overlapped.

Comment: Edric, I tested the arrayfun suggestion. fortunately it resulted in better performance. the first test got 5.43 seconds (in comparison to the initial 17 seconds result) which shows about 300% boost.  however still slow in comparison to 0.009 of cpu (540 folds!)