# is using gpuArray instead of array in matlab more performant?

Tags: arrays, matlab, gpu, gpuarray

If i use any function in the list at the following link:

[Run Built-In Functions on a GPU](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/run-built-in-functions-on-a-gpu.html)
with the argument being of the type **gpuArray** instead of **array**, will the result be computed faster? If the answer is yes, is there some case where it is more convinient to use an **array** instead of a **gpuArray**?

It is claimed that this question is a duplicate of this one:

[why MATLAB gpuarray is much slower in just adding two matrices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27363660/why-matlab-gpuarray-is-much-slower-in-just-adding-two-matrices)

This is clearly not the case, since I am asking in a general manner, while this is comparing CPU to GPU for a specific code. At most, that link should provide an answer to this question.

Comment: @rayryeng see my edit on the question about the duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

According to the official documentation:

[Measure and Improve GPU Performance](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html)
there exists at least one case where the CPU is more performant than the GPU, so the general answer is that the GPU does not necessarily compute faster:

> On the same machine, this code displays the output:
>
> Execution time on CPU = 0.019335
>
> Execution time on GPU = 0.027235

I found this documentation to answer this question and provide an answer to those such as

- Best Practices for Improving Performance
- Comparison between increasing performance on the CPU and the GPU